# Как скомпилировать проект нейронной сети с пользовательским интерфейсом, в приложения для Windows на Pycharm

Tags: pip, pyinstaller, install

Подскажите пожалуйста как скомпилировать нейросеть и весь проект на Python в приложения для использования на Windows. Пробовал через библеотеку Pyinstaller. Но вышло бездарно...=(
Получается с компилировать только один фаил. В целом если есть с кем можно проконсультировтся по поводу правильности написания нейросети буду рад. Мои контакты @Lonkeras (Telegram)